# Bootstrap Navbar list items/links not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4

I am learning to use Bootstrap and playing with components, specifically the navbar.

My links/list items aren't showing. I have copied code directly from Bootstrap.
I'm hoping someone could please explain what I'm missing.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>NavBar</title>

    <!-- bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>    
<body>      
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>   
</body>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **Bootstrap 4**, the `navbar-expand-*` class is needed to show the horizontal navbar, otherwise it will collapse into it's mobile state.

Make sure you've referenced it properly in the Codepen as https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

***Or***, use Codeply, and it will include the all the relevant libraries for you: 
[Bootstrap 4 on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.0.alpha.6)

Here's the Navbar with **Bootstrap 4.0.0**: 
http://www.codeply.com/go/SmEyy7rg5S

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

---

Related: [Disable responsive navbar in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945176/disable-responsive-navbar-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 2):

your reference to their css file is not what is listed on their website. use the following:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

your java script file is also not what is listed:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

here is where you can find the latest links to their most up-to-date CDN's: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

you are have probably copied that from an experimental place. (it says alpha within the file name so there are more than likely some bugs)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the alpha version of bootstrap. This version may contain a bug. You might want to use the latest stable version. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708398/6911703) has the links to the correct css and js files for version 3.3.7. If bootstrap is updated after this answer, you can download the latest version at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/. Hope this helps!

Albert